# Are blowfish and twofish encrypted byte by byte?

Tags: c++, blowfish, twofish

I am receiving packets through network. But some of those packets have dynamic length, so second byte has a 2 bytes long WORD that contains length. So I receive the packet number first, then receive all according to the length. Everything is okay here, when there is no encryption. Will it be same if i use twofish or blowfish encryption ? What i mean is, 'A' is encrypted as 'B' but will 'AA' be encrypted as 'BB' ? Can i extract a byte and decrypt it from a packet encrypted with TF/BF as whole ?

Comment: guess  why they are called "block cipher"

Answer (score 1):

> What i mean is, 'A' is encrypted as 'B' but will 'AA' be encrypted as 'BB' ?

A sensible encryption algorithm will never do this, otherwise the encrypted info can be easily broken by frequency analysis. (This is known as [substitution cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher), by the way). This is of course true* for [blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_%28cipher%29) and [twofish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twofish).

Even if you want to extract a byte in the middle, you have to decrypt the whole packet first.

---

*: unless you use the weak [ECB mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29), which only reduces the two encryption algorithms into substitution ciphers over 64-bit/128-bit blocks).

Answer (score 1):

Generally the answer is to pad the encrypted data. Don't just pad by adding 0's until you get to the block length, however; padding can give away a bit too much information.

As far as extracting a byte, depending on the cipher mode used - how the cipher is changed between blocks - you should not be able to do this. You'll need to decrypt all the way up the byte byte you'd like to read. It is general practice for the encryption to be "transparent" - i.e. you do your network programming, then slap SSL onto it, so that SSL handles encrypting everything, dealing with variable lengths, etc. and you just get to deal with plain old data.

As to whether throwing SSL at it is a good idea with your design, I have no idea, but you can use the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Twofish, at its base level, encodes 16-byte blocks. So the minimum piece of Twofish-encrypted data you can have is 16 bytes long. If your data contains the length, then you can decrypt it then throw away any extra bytes in the last block.

So to encrypt 'A' you need to pad it (somehow - there are various ways - all zeroes is apparently not the best way) to 16 bytes, then encrypt your one byte of data and your 15 unwanted bytes. You get a 16-byte encrypted block. On decryption you can throw away the extra bytes.

I suggest half an hour reading these Wikipedia articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29

Both of them have been helpful to me.